# Haircuts Erev Pesach

Tags: passover, halacha, hair, minor-katan-child

Are you allowed to take a Haircut The day of Erev Pesach after Burning the Chometz? Does it make a difference if your are a Male or female are small children Different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as it is before *Hatzos* then it may be done *Lechatehilah*. [If it is after *Hatzos* then it may be done by a non-Jew.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14169&st=&pgnum=151)(SA OC 468 1 MB 5)

Under *Bar* or *Bas Mitzvah* may be given a haircut after *Hatzos Lechatihilah*.

Comment: Source, please.

Comment: Mishnah Berurah 468:5.

Comment: Just to point out that this means men who want to shave before the start of chag/sefira need to do so _before_ noon.