# Shaving on Friday when Lag Ba'omer falls out on a Sunday

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, hair, shaving, lag-ba-omer

This year (2011, 2017) Lag Ba'omer falls out on a Sunday. I've heard from a few people that the halacha is that you can shave (and take a haircut) on the Friday beforehand l'kavod Shabbos. Are there any sources for that? Any extra day I don't need to live with this beard is a good day for me :)

Comment: Just saw this on VIN: http://www.vosizneias.com/84049/2011/05/19/new-york-haircuts-on-friday-before-lag-baomer-a-halachic-analysis

Comment: May you take a haircut on Thursday night?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 493:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2265), Rema:

> ואין להסתפר עד ל"ג בעצמו ולא מבערב.
>   מיהו אם חל ביום ראשון, נוהגין להסתפר
>   ביום ששי לכבוד שבת
>
> And it is not permitted to get a
>   haircut [or shave] until the day of
>   the Lag b'Omer itself. However, if it
>   [Lag b'Omer] falls on Sunday, we have
>   a custom to get haircuts [and shave]
>   on Friday, in honor of Shabbat.

Comment: Just for the record, this is a Machloket Rishonim. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14721&st=&pgnum=41&hilite= Here is the Maharil where he notes that those (namely, Mahari Weill) that permit in this case are holding avoid haircuts during the Omer isn't actually a Minhag but just something a few people do. It's questionable that they would still permit today when avoiding haircuts is about as near-universal Minhag as you can imagine.

Comment: Also note that those who keep Lad B'omer would not be able to rely on this heter, since the heter is for pushing up from *Sunday*, not Monday. I don't believe the calendar allows Lad to fall out on Sunday.

Comment: The Levush says this is only in places where you wouldn't be able to get a haircut on Sunday because all the shops are closed for the Christian holiday. Perforce then we have to let you get it early.

Answer (score 7):

Footnote 61 of [*Halachically Speaking*](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/) Volume 7, [Issue 5 (PDF)](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Volume_7_Issue_5.pdf) says:

> Chok Yaakov 7, Shulchan Aruch Harav 5, Chayei Adom 131:11, Mishnah Berurah 5, Aruch Hashulchan 6, L’Torah V’horah 2: page 19:2 quoting the opinion of Harav Moshe Feinstein, zt’l, Rivevos Ephraim 6: page 294:2, Orchos Rabbeinu 2: page 95:11, see Chok Yaakov 7. This is even according to the Sefardim (Bais Dovid 208). Lag B’omer falls out on Sunday in the following years (5771, 73, 74, 77, 84, 88, 91, 94, 95, 97, 98). Some say to take the haircut on Friday after chatzos if possible, although taking it before chatzos is also permitted (Halichos Shlomo Moadim 2: page 364: footnote 79).

Comment: Sure, but are there any other sources?

Comment: Who said taking a haircut on friday afternoon is muttar at all? See OC 251

Comment: @Double AA OC 251 (2) says וּמִסְתַּפְּרִין כָּל הַיּוֹם, אֲפִלּוּ מִסַּפַּר יִשְׂרָאֵל.!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That's quite a controverial position. Note the Beuir Halakha there  עיין בביאור הגר"א שמפקפק בזה מאד ולפי דעתו יש ליזהר ממנחה ולמעלה אפי' בחנם כי היא תמיד מלאכת אומן ע"ש: and recall from Erev Pesach https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6928/759

Answer (score 5):

See [Halachically Speaking  Volume 3 Issue 16](https://web.archive.org/web/20120522204320/http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume3/Issue16.pdf) page 5:

> When Lag B’omer falls out on Sunday (as it does this year) shaving etc. is permitted on Friday because of kovod for Shabbos <sup>64</sup>. The reason why it is kovod for Shabbos is because by the mincha before Lag B’omer one does not say tachnun, so technically shaving would permitted on Shabbos, but since one can not do so, the allowance is pushed back to Friday <sup>65</sup>.  One may not shave etc. on Motzei Shabbos when Lag B’omer falls out on Sunday <sup>66</sup>. Furthermore, many say that shaving etc. in the above situation is not permitted on Thursday night [Thursday night is technically Friday] if one has time to do it on Friday <sup>67</sup>. [...]

Footnotes excerpt (in case the link goes down again):

> 64. Rama ibid [493:2], Chok Yaakov 7, Shulchan Aruch Harav 5, Chai Adom 131:11, Mishnah Berurah 5, Aruch Ha’shulchan 6, L’Torah
>       V’horah 2:page 19:2 quoting the opinion of Horav Moshe Feinstein zt”l, Rivevos Ephraim 6:page 294:2, Orchos Rabbeinu 2:page
>       95:11, see Chok Yaakov 7. This is even according to the Sefardim (Bais Dovid 208). Lag B’omer falls out on Sunday in the following
>       years (5767, 70, 71, 73, 74, 77, 84, 88, 91, 94, 95, 97, 98). Some say to take the haircut on Friday after chatzos if possible, although
>       taking it before chatzos is also permitted (Halichos Shlomo Moadim 2:page 364:footnote 79).
> 65. Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita. Refer to Nodeh B’Yehuda 1:28:page 64 (old).
> 66. Ben Pesach L’Shavuos page 250:foontoe 20 quoting the opinion of Horav Elyashiv Shlita, Doleh U’mashka page 196, Halichos
>       Shlomo Moadim 2:page 364:footnote 31.
> 67. Refer to Refer to Mishnah Berurah 260:5, Rivevos Ephraim 1:338, 4:131, see Kaf Ha’chaim 23, Ben Pesach L’Shavuos page 250.
>       One who did not cut his hair in this situation until Sunday was not mezalzel in the honor of Shabbos (Rivevos Ephraim 1:338).

Note: anything in brackets in the quotes above is written by me.

Comment: @doubleAA there is a Posek Hador who allows shaving on a regular year the day before lag bomer because tachanun isnt said starting from mincha,see the Be'er Heitiv as well

Comment: @sam If they permit on 32 afternoon because of no Tachanun, then they should permit shaving Saturday night as well. One way or another this article is contradicting itself.

Comment: @sam do they permit on pesach sheni for nusach sfard that skips tachanun?

Comment: No,only mincha before lag baomer,also pesach sheni is not a yom tov

Comment: @sam Why not have for pesach sheni for nusach sfard? (lag baomer is not a yom tov either... I'm not saying I understand why one would skip tachanun on pesach sheni, just saying it should follow according to that opinion)

Comment: I'm saying that the lifting of aveilus happens on lag baomer,as opposed to pesach sheni ,that's the diff

Comment: @sam that's anachronistic. the rishonei ashkenaz who are disputing tachanun on 32 afternoon are all keeping second half (where aveilus isn't lifted on lag baomer permanently) because there are 33 days with tachanun there. seemingly for them the reason to shave on 32 afternoon for those not saying tachanun is because it's a time without tachanun. see the source of the beir heitiv in malbushei yom tov https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33745&st=&pgnum=108 (remember to ping me `@DoubleAA`)

Comment: Mahari Asad rules that the Rama is only prohibiting haircuts on 32 afternoon, but 33 at night is permitted. Accordingly, it follows that those who forbid haircuts 33 at night would not allow them on Friday 31, since the logic from Avelut that ends on Shabbat doesn't apply.