# Haircuts on Friday when the 47th of the omer falls on Sunday

Tags: halacha, minhag, sefirat-ha-omer, mourning-aveilus

The [Rema](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14327&st=&pgnum=172), commenting on the mourning of the first 33 days of the omer, allows haircuts on Friday, lichvod shabbos, when the 33rd falls on Sunday.

Does the same reasoning apply when the 47th falls on Sunday (for those who keep Iyar- aka "the 2nd half")?  Or is there something specific pertaining to Lag Ba'omer?  The Rema does not repeat the permit after introducing the Iyar minhag, but he could be expecting someone to make the comparison.

Comment: It would seem the same Machloket (Maharil vs Mahariv) would apply.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7520/759

Comment: Same question for 47 on Friday for those who don't shave until 49.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nit'ei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&st=&pgnum=286) brings a disagreement between poskim in this matter. He writes, therefore, that one should be stringent, but in a pressing situation (מקום צורך), one may be lenient.

Comment: Thanks, jake, that was helpful.  It's strange that someone who was bringing both opinions and being machria would be machmir in light of the fact that at best it's a minhag.  The Chok Yaakov on the previous page of my link, clearly writes not to be machmir for a safek.  This is brought by the Be'er Hetiv (6) as well.  Any idea if R' Moshe's psak was written?  Siman?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/weekly_torah.php?id=901), R' Moshe is quoted in L'Torah V'horah 2, p.19-20. Sounds like it is not a written p'sak.

Answer (score 1):

The Ezras Torah calendar in which the laws are supposed to be based of the opinions of Rabbi Yosef Eliyahu Henkin, gives permission to groom on the Friday before Lag B'Omer but not on the Friday before the three days of hagbalah. I would assume the the difference is because in the latter case the Friday is Rosh Chodesh and many prohibit grooming on any Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: Does the calender prohibit grooming on other Rashei Chodoshim?

Comment: Hi mocdeg! If you are the same mocdeg as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2128/mocdeg then consider contacting Stack Exchange [here to merge your accounts](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge). Either way, welcome aboard!

Comment: In addition to merging accounts, per @DoubleAA's advice, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will prevent this kind of issue from happening again, and will also [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: I looked at the first Rosh Chodesh in the calendar for 5773 and there is no mention of grooming.

Comment: _mod note_ This was written to a duplicate question and merged hither.

Comment: What about when Friday is the 47th for those who usually wait until the 49th to shave? Then Rosh Chodesh is not a factor