# May One Shave On Thursday Night - When Lag Baomer Falls Out On Sunday

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, shaving

Because Lag Baomer falls out on Sunday, we are allowed to [shave/haircut on Friday](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/shaving-on-friday-when-lag-baomer-falls-out-on-a-sunday?rq=1) - Lekavod Shabbos (Rema-Orach Chayim 493:2)

However, is one allowed to shave/haircut tonight (i.e. Thursday night), which is halachically erev shabbos?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14721&st=&pgnum=41&hilite= Here is the Maharil where he notes that those (namely, Mahari Weill) that permit in this case are holding avoid haircuts during the Omer isn't actually a Minhag but just something a few people do. It's questionable that they would still permit today when avoiding haircuts is about as near-universal Minhag as you can imagine.

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv You could make this question more compelling by [edit]ing in more detail about why you think the night of Yom Shishi (Thursday night) may be different from the daytime of Yom Shishi.

Comment: Friday 12:01am is clearly asked about in the other post which asked about Friday. Unless you have reason to think Thursday 11:50 pm should be different (there is no such reason), then this is a duplicate. Plus the simple reading of the other post is "Friday=Yom Shishi" not "Friday=midnight to midnight" so it's a duplicate anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA MY QUESTION IS SIMPLY THIS: Is one allowed to shave on Thursday night (8pm for example) because it is night and halachically the next day ie. Erev shabbos. The supposed dupe is asking for the source that allows for one to shave on a Friday when Lag Baomer falls out on Sunday. It is simply asking for a source. I am asking one step further, i.e. That once we know that Friday is allowed, is that heter allowed for Leil Shishi? Or only for Friday Day (and the answer,I have just learned, is that if one has the time on Friday, he should wait till Friday DAY, and rely on mikztas Hayom Kekulo

Comment: Perhaps a better way to ask this would be that there's a machlokes in the poskim whether one may shave on Lag B'omer night or wait until Lag B'omer day. Does the same machlokes apply to the Thursday night before a Sunday Lag B'omer? If you phrased it that way, I'd say it's not a dupe, but as it stands I don't see why it should be any different. @DoubleAA

Comment: @IsaacMoses ^^^

Comment: Shoel I agree this is not a dupe, but why would this case be more lenient than lag baomer itself? Lag Baomer we don't shave till the morning. Why should 31st baomer be better? (Btw, R' S.Z. Aurbach says lichatchila to wait till aftet chatzos on friday for shaving and haircuts.)